# Getting wiki output from TinyMCE/CKEditor (for Trac plugin)

Tags: javascript, open-source, tinymce, ckeditor, trac

I'm working for a company that uses Trac. Problem is, no one likes Trac's wiki-editor, and the wysiwyg plugin isn't as good as we'd like.

To solve this, we've decided to create our own Trac wysiwyg plugin (hopefully, I'll be allowed to Opensource it.)

The plan right now is to use either TinyMCE or CKEditor as they wysiwyg editor. Problem is, their output is html. Ideally, we'd like their output to be native trac-wiki code.

**My question:** Is there any way of getting TinyMCE or CKEditor to output wiki code instead of html? If not, what's the best way to make them output wiki? (I assume they have some kind of plugin interface I can use? Which is better for this kind of thing?)

Meta-question: what do you think of my approach? Is there a better/faster way of getting what I want than integrating TinyMCE/CKEditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before making your own check [TinyMce Wiki Plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TinyMceWikiPlugin)

Comment: We've already looked at it. It seems incredibly out-of-date (last supported version is an old Trac version, last check-in is from 2006 if I' not mistaken.) That's why it seemed to be better to start from scratch. Do you have any experience with the plugin that would suggest otherwise?