# Wysiwyg editor that outputs mediawiki/tracwiki

Tags: javascript, editor, wysiwyg, mediawiki

(Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509431/getting-wiki-output-from-tinymce-ckeditor-for-trac-plugin).)

I'm looking for a wysiwyg editor, but which outputs mediawiki (or, preferably,tracwiki) syntax **instead of html**.

I've worked with TinyMCE and CKEditor in the past, but both of them are only built to output html. There is an undergoing project for adding CKEditor to mediawiki, but it's only in alpha, and it's developed as a plugin for mediawiki, not as a standalone editor.

Thanks!
P.S. I added this question since my original question asked specifically about TinyMCE and CKEditor, which is something different. Hope that's alright.

Comment: MarkItUp (http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) might be something you can hack to give you what you need. It's an alternate implementation of the same kind of editor that's used on StackOverflow, with support for HTML, Textile, BBCode, Wiki, and Dotclear's markup syntaxes as well as Markdown. It *isn't* a WYSIWYG editor though. (http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't a lot of stuff outside of the CKEditor -- however, there are a few tools for exporting from MS Word to mediawiki format (although that might create a bigger problem instead of helping).

In any case, there is some more information about this here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Tools#Importing_.28converting.29_content_to_Wikipedia_.28MediaWiki.29_format

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of projects, [VisualEditor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Visual_editor) and [Parsoid](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid), which together will solve this problem. They are still under active development but you can play with a demo on [MediaWiki.org](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/VisualEditor%3aWelcome). Both of these projects are free open source software (VisualEditor is under MIT and Parsoid is under GPL).